# display all values of table even without value in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have been working for this for 2 days and i can't combine my tables with 3 different status for example approved, rejected and pending..

In this query it only display all the approved

```
 Select * from
    productdesignapproval a,
    productinformation b,
    department c,
    subdivision e,
    class f,
    subclass g,
    productseason h,
    year i,
    productstylecode j,
    productgenericnumber k, 
    users l
    WHERE
    a.productinformationID = b.productinformationID AND
    b.departmentID = c.departmentID AND
    b.subdivisionID = e.subdivisionID AND
    b.classID = f.classID AND
    b.subclassID = g.subclassID AND
    b.productseasonID = h.productseasonID AND
    b.yearID = i.yearID AND
    a.productinformationID = j.productinformationID AND
    a.productinformationID = k.productinformationID AND
    l.userID = a.designerID AND a.approvalstatus = 'Approved'
```

If i changed the a.approvalstatus to Pending there's no value that will appear

THe database works like this if the design is approved there is a specific 
productstylecode j, productgenericnumber k, and if not this is my query

```
Select * from
    productdesignapproval a,
    productinformation b,
    department c,
    subdivision e,
    class f,
    subclass g,
    productseason h,
    year i,
    users l
    WHERE
    a.productinformationID = b.productinformationID AND
    b.departmentID = c.departmentID AND
    b.subdivisionID = e.subdivisionID AND
    b.classID = f.classID AND
    b.subclassID = g.subclassID AND
    b.productseasonID = h.productseasonID AND
    b.yearID = i.yearID AND
    l.userID = a.designerID AND 
    a.approvalstatus != 'Approved'
```

if the value is pending/rejected there's no productstylecode and genericnumber.

Question how can i combine the 2 tables into 1 table? so i can display all approved with product style code and generic number and all pending and rejected without product style code and generic number. Thanks!

Comment: you can use `union` but take note , they must have the same columns

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need something like this query

```
SELECT * FROM
productdesignapproval a
JOIN productinformation b ON a.productinformationID = b.productinformationID
JOIN department c ON b.departmentID = c.departmentID
JOIN subdivision e ON b.subdivisionID = e.subdivisionID
JOIN class f ON b.classID = f.classID
JOIN subclass g ON b.subclassID = g.subclassID
JOIN productseason h ON b.productseasonID = h.productseasonID
JOIN year i ON b.yearID = i.yearID
JOIN users l ON l.userID = a.designerID
LEFT JOIN productstylecode j ON a.productinformationID = j.productinformationID AND a.approvalstatus = 'Approved'
LEFT JOIN productgenericnumber k ON a.productinformationID = k.productinformationID AND a.approvalstatus = 'Approved'
```

Comment: I have another question you already displayed all the approved, pending and rejected but in pending and rejected the PIF# is not displaying. but in approved it works fine? can you help me again?